# Reference Android libraries from Xamarin application

Tags: android, xamarin

I am now converting a piece of native Android application written in Java to Xamarin/C#. I am stuck at the piece of code that uses AttributeSet class (placed originally in android.util package). How can I get that reference as part of my Xamarin application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AttributeSet actually is not a class, it is an interface. With Xamarin it is named accordingly, IAttributeSet.

```
Android.Util.IAttributeSet attrSet = Android.Util.Xml.AsAttributeSet(...
```